# How to get cancellation policy for Sabre Flights

Tags: .net, sabre

I have used `InstaFlightSearch` to get the flight segments. But I want to get cancellation policy details. I don't know what Sabre API does provide the detail? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AirPricing_RulesFromPriceRQ API
As well as RulesFromPriceLLSRQ